# Concatenate a variable onto the end of another variable or string in Bash

Tags: bash

I need to create many variables that begin with "precip" followed by a dynamic string which is a read in variable.  I read this variable in, let's say its "1971" and then I increment it by 5 a bunch of times to create five or so variables spanning the range from 1971, 1976, 1981, etc.  I need to append each of these variables (named yr1, yr2, yr3...) to the the "precip" variable.

As an example, instead of the hard coded variables found below:

```
precip1971="pr_"$reg"_"$glob"_1971010103.nc"  
precip1976="pr_"$reg"_"$glob"_1976010103.nc"
precip1981="pr_"$reg"_"$glob"_1981010103.nc"
precip1986="pr_"$reg"_"$glob"_1986010103.nc"
precip1991="pr_"$reg"_"$glob"_1991010103.nc"
precip1996="pr_"$reg"_"$glob"_1996010103.nc"
```

I would like something like (knowing this below is wrong):

```
precip+yr1="pr_"$reg"_"$glob"_1971010103.nc"  
precip+yr2="pr_"$reg"_"$glob"_1976010103.nc"
precip+yr3="pr_"$reg"_"$glob"_1981010103.nc"
precip+yr4="pr_"$reg"_"$glob"_1986010103.nc"
precip+yr5="pr_"$reg"_"$glob"_1991010103.nc"
precip+yr6="pr_"$reg"_"$glob"_1996010103.nc"
```

so that precip+yr1 equals a variable named precip1971, precip+yr2 equals a variable named precip1976, and so on.

I have found ways to concatenate two variables' values, but not a new variable with the value of an existing variable.

Is there a way to do this in Bash?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you considered using an *array*, with the year as its index, like `precip[1971]`,`precip[1972]` etc.?

Comment: I have not - I guess I don't understand how that would help.  New to Bash and trying my best to pick it u quickly.

Comment: @steeldriver please, write down the answer using arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `eval` to evaluate the variable assignment. Below is a sample program related to your scenario.

```
#!/bin/bash

year=1971

for ((i=0; i<=10; i++))
do
    eval precip${year}="pr_${reg}_${glob}_1971010103.nc" 
    ((year+=5))
done
```

Here the `eval` statement evaluates the variable `precip${year}` to `precip1971` and so on.